# Elmah isn't saving errors

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nuget, elmah

I just installed Elmah is Nuget and it shows teh errors, but when I restart my web application, it doesn't have the old one, how do I configure it to save it? I thought it would do that automatically..

Comment: The default configuration is to use an in-memory storage, you need to configure it to use a physical storage location, like XML or Database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the default provider, your error log won't survive application restarts because it's stored in memory. Choose a different provider instead, such as XML file or one of the database ones, such as `Elmah.SqlErrorLog` - you need to edit the `web.config` file to change this.

There's more info on the web. For example:

http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/DotNetSlackersArticle#Storing_errors_in_memory

http://www.devcurry.com/2012/05/error-handling-elmah-in-aspnet-mvc.html